# named network unreachable on boot

Tags: networking, archlinux

Another problem I found out in Arch Linux is if you're rebooting the Raspberry Pi with `reboot` and having `named` in the `systemctl startup` it will throw a long list of errors resulting in not working properly.

The last lines of `/var/log/messages.log`:

```
Jan  1 01:00:30 raspberrypi named[294]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'raspberrypi/A/IN': 192.5.5.241#53
Jan  1 01:00:30 raspberrypi named[294]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'raspberrypi/A/IN': 193.0.14.129#53
Jan  1 01:00:30 raspberrypi named[294]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'raspberrypi/A/IN': 199.7.83.42#53
Jan  1 01:00:30 raspberrypi named[294]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'raspberrypi/A/IN': 2001:500:2d::d#53
Jan  1 01:00:30 raspberrypi named[294]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'raspberrypi/A/IN': 2001:7fe::53#53
Jan  1 01:00:30 raspberrypi named[294]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'raspberrypi/A/IN': 2001:503:c27::2:30#53
Jan  1 01:00:30 raspberrypi named[294]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'raspberrypi/A/IN': 2001:503:ba3e::2:30#53
Jan  1 01:00:30 raspberrypi named[294]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'raspberrypi/A/IN': 2001:500:1::803f:235#53
Jan  1 01:00:30 raspberrypi named[294]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'raspberrypi/A/IN': 202.12.27.33#53
Jan  1 01:00:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Samba SMB/CIFS server.
Jan  1 01:00:30 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[122]: dbus[122]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Avahi' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service'
Jan  1 01:00:30 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[122]: dbus[122]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service': Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service' for details.
Jan  1 01:00:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[287]: eth0: leased 192.168.178.* for 3600 seconds
Jan  1 01:00:35 raspberrypi named[294]: checkhints: unable to get root NS rrset from cache: not found
Jan  1 01:00:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started OpenNTP Daemon.
Jan  1 01:00:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Multi-User System.
Jan  1 01:00:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
Jan  1 01:00:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Graphical Interface.
Jan  1 01:00:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical Interface.
Jan  1 01:00:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Startup finished in 2.839s (kernel) + 38.816s (userspace) = 41.656s.
```

I can see that the named server is starting before network is initialized so **how can I get the named server be started after network has been initialized?**

Starting it later over ssh with `systemctl restart named` is not an option.
This may cause problems in systems where the Raspberry Pi is used as default nameserver like an intranet.

`/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Internet domain name server
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -f -u named
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/rndc reload
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rndc stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: My pi has problems with the network on arch as well. Netcfg always fails on startup, but if I run it manually later, it works. I only say this because I sympathize with your plight. Perhaps you could write a startup script that has a delay built into it and later brings up the server?

Comment: do you know how I could delay the start up in the `.service`-file without using a separate start up script? I don't really find any information about how to start a service delayed. @krs013

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. I'm just beginning to learn arch myself. But maybe if your could edit the script that starts the daemon (if it is a script and not just a binary file, but you could make a script for it in its place, I guess) you could add something like a sleep statement there for a minute or however long it takes. However, if it's a universal problem someone should really figure out how to fix it in an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it's not really an answer but a workaround.
I knew of another name server `dnsmasq` which works fine now.

What I did:
`pacman -S dnsmasq` and `pacman -R bind`. Replace `bind` with `dnsmasq`.
Edited the `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` to fit my requirements and enabled it via `systemctl enable dnsmasq`. Rebooted and everything works fine. For everyone who does not want to want to edit the bind-files this is a good and fast alternative.